# How to Laravel Mysql fetch data from database using multiple table join

Tags: mysql, laravel, database

This is my data retrieving query:

```
$admin_students=DB::select("select students.*,application_record.*,gender_record.*,
application_record.id as app_primary_id,application_record.status as app_status from students 
left join application_record on application_record.student_id=students.id 
left join application_record on application_record.gender_record_id=gender_record.name");
```

Table structure

```
Table 1 = application_record - > id, name, status, gender_record_id, .... 

Table 2 = gender_record - > id, name
```

Now how can I return the `Gender Name` using the `Gender Record ID` which is the primary key for "Table 2"?

Answer (score 2):

```
   DB:: table('students')
    ->leftjoin('application_record, 'students.id','=' , 'application_record.student_id' )
    ->leftjoin('gender_record','application_record.gender_record_id','=','gender_record.id')->select('students.*',' application_record.*,
    'gender_record.*,)->get();
```